# Please re-tag "viewsonic-g-tablet" to "viewsonic-gtablet"

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

The official name of the thing is *gTablet*.[<sup>1</sup>](http://www1.viewsonic.com/gtablet/)

To fit with our `manufacturer-name` scheme for device tags, please retag [viewsonic-g-tablet](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/viewsonic-g-tablet) to [viewsonic-gtablet](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/viewsonic-gtablet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks right to me, I've synonymized and merged over to the new tag.

Comment: Hello, I created the tag OP is talking about, sorry: my mistake. I don't want to go wrong anymore when creating tags, so: How is this thing about manufacturer-name scheme for device tags? Are there some rules about it? If so, where can I find them?

Comment: @FranciscoAlvarado There's nothing really formal.  Just try to use the most common name; `lg-optimus-one` is better than `lg-p1550` for example (I made up that model name).